# crystal reports viewer does not load when asp.net application is deployed to server

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

On my local build, when I open the page that has the crystal reports viewer - everything loads and looks fine (the crystal reports viewer actually shows up on the page). when I copied this over to the server for the web (and installed the CR framework for the correct version) - the crystal reports viewer does not load when opening the page, so I just get a blank page that says done with nothing loaded. Has anyone else ran into this issue?

edit - after restarting the server i am getting the following error. - error is at line 24

when running on local build still works, code on server is exactly the same, not sure why I am receiving this error. Thanks

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4DB2E2BB-78E6-4AEA-BEFB-        FDAAB610FD1B} failed due to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E). 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web     request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4DB2E2BB-78E6-4AEA-BEFB-FDAAB610FD1B} failed due to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

Source Error: 


Line 22:         ReportSourceID="McNeil_source" ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="" ToolPanelWidth="200px" 
Line 23:         Width="2304px" HasRefreshButton="True"></CR:CrystalReportViewer>
Line 24:     <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="McNeil_source" runat="server">
Line 25:         <Report FileName="CrystalReport2.rpt">
Line 26:         </Report>


Source File: C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\iPlan 7 Layer QA\WorkingDirectory\excel import.aspx    Line: 24
```

here is the stack trace

```
[FileNotFoundException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4DB2E2BB-78E6-4AEA-BEFB-FDAAB610FD1B} failed due to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).]
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor() +193

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception.]
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..ctor() +44
   CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.CachedReport.get_ReportDocument() +39
   CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportSource.set_Report(Report value) +218
   ASP.excel_import_aspx.__BuildControlMcNeil_source() in C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\iPlan 7 Layer QA\WorkingDirectory\excel import.aspx:24
   ASP.excel_import_aspx.__BuildControlform1() in C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\iPlan 7 Layer QA\WorkingDirectory\excel import.aspx:16
   ASP.excel_import_aspx.__BuildControlTree(excel_import_aspx __ctrl) in C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\iPlan 7 Layer QA\WorkingDirectory\excel import.aspx:1
   ASP.excel_import_aspx.FrameworkInitialize() +46
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +78
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +49
   ASP.excel_import_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +37
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +100
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

i removed the 32 bit version, installed the 64 and got a new error, here it is

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error: 


Line 18:     
Line 19:     </div>
Line 20:     <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
Line 21:         AutoDataBind="True" GroupTreeImagesFolderUrl="" Height="962px" 
Line 22:         ReportSourceID="McNeil_source" ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="" ToolPanelWidth="200px" 


Source File: C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\iPlan 7 Layer QA\WorkingDirectory\excel import.aspx    Line: 20 

Stack Trace: 


[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer..cctor() +0

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for     'CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer' threw an exception.]
   CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer..ctor() +19
   ASP.excel_import_aspx.__BuildControlCrystalReportViewer1() in C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\iPlan 7 Layer QA\WorkingDirectory\excel import.aspx:20
   ASP.excel_import_aspx.__BuildControlform1() in C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\iPlan 7 Layer QA\WorkingDirectory\excel import.aspx:16
   ASP.excel_import_aspx.__BuildControlTree(excel_import_aspx __ctrl) in C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\iPlan 7 Layer QA\WorkingDirectory\excel import.aspx:1
   ASP.excel_import_aspx.FrameworkInitialize() +46
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +78
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +49
   ASP.excel_import_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +37
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +100
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET     Version:4.0.30319.1
```

I am also recieving this error in other pages on the site

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


Line 34:           debugging ASP.NET files.
Line 35:     -->
Line 36:     <compilation defaultLanguage="vb" debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">    <assemblies><add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/><add     assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/><add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared,     Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/><add     assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/><add     assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/></assemblies></compilation>
Line 37:     <!--  CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGES
Line 38:           Set customErrors mode="On" or "RemoteOnly" to enable custom error     messages, "Off" to disable. 


Source File: C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\iPlan 7 Layer QA\WorkingDirectory\web.config    Line: 36 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET     Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Comment: I added the stack trace, does that give any clues? Thanks again

Comment: did you install the correct runtimes? which visual studio version? which crystal version? which .net framework? which server o/s? iis version? is the server x86 or x64?

Comment: i installed the 32 - the 32 loaded the blank page where the report should have been. i uninstalled it, restarted, installed the 64 bit, got an error on my main page due to the config so i knew it was wrong, uninstalled the 64 bit, restarted, reinstalled the 32 and now instead of a blank page I am getting the above error, so the 32 is currently installed.

Comment: is the application pool for the website/application set to allow 32-bit execution?

Comment: not sure off the top of my head, where in iis would i check that?

Comment: https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/KB/a1114/how-to-enable-a-32-bit-application-pool-in-iis7-dedicatedvps.aspx

Comment: the rest of the site is in 64, so i am currently uninstalling the 32 and reinstalling the 64, should take a few minutes. thank you for all your help

Comment: ok, back to 64 bit which is working differently than the first time, the whole site works except this page, editing my first post to show the new error message, which says it deals with log4net

Comment: posted new error message, any clues? thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite common with Crystal Reports .net deployments. There tend to be differences (sometimes subtle) between the development machine(s) and the production server(s).

First things to check are:

- Architecture (x86, x64)
- Crystal Runtime Version

If these don't match you're going to have problems :)

Comment: added new error message above, im pretty sure architecture and crystal runtime version match

Comment: between lee's fix and a permissions error, this issue is solved. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and 'was able to resolve it. Here is the solution I did:

Some deployment notes per Crystal Reports:

A. Download and install Crystal Reports from this URL:
    http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_1.zip

B. Do following to update your web app/site in IIS so Crystal Report viewer will work:

Crystal Reports redistributable package is installing the report view files on a location different than where the Visual Studio 2010 
Crystal Report control expects it to be, thus, the report was not getting rendered. 
I saw this issue upon looking at the HTML output and experimented with copying the "viewer" files where the control expects them to be. 
After doing this, it started to work.

Copy the "crystal report viewer" files from this install location:
C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\Crystal Reports 2011\crystalreportviewers
Onto this folder:
    \aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13
(In our qa2 server, the folder is: D:\websites\qa2-internal.credomobile.com\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13)

Answer (score 0):

Could not load file or assembly 'log4net...

At least with the 64bit version that's a problem in your stack trace.  Install log4net on the server.

Comment: log4net is installed and working with other sites on the server - i am also recieving errors relating to the crystal reports plugins - will post error to bottom of first post

Comment: log4net error with Crystal Reports comes when you have installed 32-bit or 64-bit CR run-time on inappropriate platform, even though log4net appears in GAC.