# VS 2010, SAP Crystal Reports, Windows Server 2008

Tags: crystal-reports

I need help I developed a Web site and added SAP Crystal reports when run it from VS 2010 in debugging mode all reports works fine, but when I try to run it from IIS with System I.P and its shows nothing no error and crystal reports shows no Reports even no blank report. . is there any issue running SAP Crystal Reports in production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [crystal reports viewer does not load when asp.net application is deployed to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624701/crystal-reports-viewer-does-not-load-when-asp-net-application-is-deployed-to-ser/9625485#9625485)

Often an issue with the run times not being installed or incorrect versions etc.

Comment: Checked this post and I have correct version installed, when saw the in page source the html contains all the reports data on runtime but not displaying it in web page. any idea?